# rspec/rails can't seem to load up with Ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Alright, I can't seem to figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. I recently updated to Ruby 2.7.1, and when I run rspec on this rails app this is what happens:

```
rspec spec/models/company_spec.rb 

An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/company_spec.rb. - Did you mean?
                    rspec ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb
                    rspec ./spec/models/deal_spec.rb
                    rspec ./spec/models/documentation_spec.rb

Failure/Error: require 'rspec/rails'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- minitest/assertions
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `<main>'
# ./spec/models/company_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is a pretty standard application, using rspec-rails. The `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb` files are nearly identical to what `rails g rspec::install` generates.

When running rspec, each file has a similar error, and points to a random different spec file with the most similar name. I've tried to include minitest in the gemfile, but that didn't do much.

I'm using rbenv, and switching back to 2.6.5 (`rbenv local 2.6.5` and `ruby '~> 2.6.5'` in the gem file) does remove the problem, but is not ideal.

Also, the issue seems limited only to rspec, since running Rails locally has no problems.

Here's my current gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '~> 2.7.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'webpacker'

# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Security gems
gem 'pundit'

# Utility gems
gem 'phony_rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

  gem 'rubocop-rails'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'
  gem 'rubocop-performance'

  gem 'table_print'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  # gem 'selenium-webdriver'  # A default not being used
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  # adding an error inspection gem
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: are you on newset rspec-rails gem?

Comment: `rspec-rails 4.0.1` according to the gemfile.lock

Comment: How does line 7 in your rails_helper.rb look like? Where does the `minitest/assertions` come from? Did you add that? Do you try to use minitest and RSpec at the same time?

Comment: line 7 just has: `require 'rspec/rails'`. I'm not using minitest anywhere, just rspec-rails.

Comment: @jfr did you try deleting your `Gemfile.lock` and did `bundle install`? And also after this try running with `bundle exec rspec spec/models/company_spec.rb`

Comment: @cdadityang just tried it. No luck, same issues.

Comment: @jfr try adding `minitest` gem in your gem file. https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest - It seems are your accidently using minitest also. Just try it out.

Comment: @cdadityang, thanks that's a pretty good suggestion. I did try it though. But I'm going to edit my question and add my gemfile, maybe there's something there I'm missing. (I added `minitest` there and removed it when there was no change.)